# How can I disable rollback on failure in my template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm working on a CloudFormation template, and an update is failing to apply. I'd like to set the stack option [Rollback on Failure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html) to "No" in order to keep the resources around for debugging. How can I disable "rollback on failure" in my CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Updated answer

You can now pass a `DisableRollback` parameter (defaults to false) when running your update stack command. See the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html

---

### Outdated

I think that option is only available on creation of a stack. The description says `Specifies whether the stack should be rolled back if stack creation fails.`.

If you look at the AWS CLI, there is a `--disable-rollback` flag available for `aws cloudformation create-stack` but no such option exists for `aws cloudformation update-stack`.

See here for references also:

- [create-stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html)
- [update-stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html)
- [Similar issues posted here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216722)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe this answer is now out of date. DisableRollback is now a request parameter for update-stack.

Comment: As @Mark says the `update-stack` command now supports the `--disable-rollback` option. With the CDK, the `cdk deploy` command supports the `--no-rollback` option.

Comment: Note that `aws cloudformation deploy` does not support `--disable-rollback`, but `aws cloudformation create-stack` and `aws cloudformation update-stack` both do. Need to use `--template-body file://whatever.yaml` instead of `--template-file whatever.yaml` for those.

Answer (score 0):

AWS introduced a CloudFormation feature where the stack creation stops at the point of failure and we should be able to debug the issue from there on. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-cloudformation-quickly-retry-stack-operations-from-the-point-of-failure/) is the reference to the AWS blog for the same.